# DBCC CHECKDB - Corrupted Pages

Tags: sql-server

On my understanding, regular run of DBCC CHECKDB is a best practice in order to check integrity of the database.

If there comes a time where a corrupted page existed, and no good back up is available, in general, what are the consequences can occur? Nothing? Corruption will spread?

Comment: Check out Steve Stedman's Corruption Challenge, https://stevestedman.com/2015/04/introducing-the-database-corruption-challenge-dbcc-week-1-challenge/?cli_action=1565710391.812, for good practice fixing corruption.

Comment: This is great post - [SQL Server Corruption – Read Before it Happens](https://straightpathsql.com/archives/2017/01/sql-server-corruption-read/)

Answer (score 1):

[`DBCC CHECKDB`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkdb-transact-sql) will also run `DBCC CHECKALLOC`, `DBCC CHECKTRABLE`, and `DBCC CHECKCATALOG`.

Running this regularly is extremely important in an effort to detect data corruption. If availability is important, you should consider running this daily. It is possible for backups to contain corrupted data as well. This can easily go unnoticed if the corrupted page(s) isn't accessed. Corruption can occur due to several factors including: storage configurations, power faults, poor cache, etc.

It is possible for corruption to spread, so be prepared! Your system and user databases should be backed up frequently with CHECKSUM and the databases be configured with the Page Verify setting set to CHECKSUM.

I would take a look at Kendra Little's [post](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/05/dbcc-checkdb-faq/) on the issue.

Brent Ozar also has a [post](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/05/dbcc-checkdb-reports-corruption/) regarding what to do when DBCC CHECKDB reports corruption.

Steve Stedman also has an excellent [Weekly Database Corruption Challenge](https://stevestedman.com/server-health/database-corruption-challenge/) if you wish to attempt repairs.

Answer (score 0):

You can repair the corrupted pages using

```
DBCC CHECKDB ('AdventureWorks2008R2', REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS);
```

But this will likely cause problems (as `ALLOW_DATA_LOSS` suggests)

Imagine you have a Person table and a Department table

```
Person Table
PersonId PersonName DepartmentId
1          John          2
2          Jane          3

Department Table
DepartmentId DepartmentName
1                 HR
2                 IT
```

lets say the corruption occured on the page that holds the DepartmentId 2 record in the Departments table, that record will be removed from the database and John is now in a department that doesn't exist (referential integrity is broken)

Tn this scenario, before we fixed the corruption, `SELECT * FROM Department` would error, whereas after running the fix it would work.

You may get lucky in that the corruption only affects indexes, views or other recreatable objects.

As for corruption spreading, if I found corruption, I would be investigating if there were any issues with the disk subsystem. If so I would expect that it would be happening again and would look into getting that fixed.

The best scenario is to have backups and to run `CHECKDB` frequently enough that you have the last good backup

Comment: True, on most points, but the OP is talking about corrupt pages explicitly and what the fallout of that is. i.e. would the server stop working? Queries to that page (only) fail? Would it get worse?